# How to display each tab contents and hide previous content when new tab loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create something like this:
http://www.keepandshare.com/userpics/d/a/v/e/8528sky/2014-11/sm/tabs-39983986.jpg?ts=1416433877
and I have:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function showTab(selected, total)
{
  for(i = 1; i <= total; i += 1)
  {
    document.getElementById('tabs-' + i).style.display = 'none';
  }

  document.getElementById('tabs-' + selected).style.display = 'block';
}
</script>

<div id="tabs-1" style="display: none">Tab1 info 1 content</div>
<div id="tabs-2" style="display: none">Tab1 info 2 content</div>
<div id="tabs-3" style="display: none">Tab1 info 3 content</div>

<ul class="side bar tabs">
  <li id = "tabs1" onclick = "showTab(1,3)">Tab1 info 1</li>
  <li id = "tabs2" onclick = "showTab(2,3)">Tab1 info 2</li>
  <li id = "tabs3" onclick = "showTab(3,3)">Tab1 info 3</li>  
</ul>
```

The problem with above code is that if I click on TAB2 and where I repeat the same code, the previous content still shows above and it needs to be hidden upon new tab content load.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see the below code.

```
 <div id="tabs-1" class="tabContent" >Tab1 info 1 content</div>
 <div id="tabs-2" class="tabContent">Tab1 info 2 content</div>
 <div id="tabs-3" class="tabContent" >Tab1 info 3 content</div>

 <ul class="side bar tabs">
  <li class="tabClicker" data-tab="tabs-1">Tab1 info 1</li>
  <li class="tabClicker" data-tab="tabs-2" >Tab1 info 2</li>
  <li class="tabClicker" data-tab="tabs-3">Tab1 info 3</li>  
 </ul>

 <script>
  $(function() {
     $(".tabClicker").click(function() {
      var tab = $(this).attr("data-tab");
       $(".tabContent").hide();
       $("#" + tab).show();
    });    
});
 </script>
     <style>
      .tabContent {
      display:none;
   }
   </style>
```

demo link.
   http://jsfiddle.net/asimshahiddIT/jrjjzw18/

Comment: Please, make your own answer instead of copying mine.

Comment: your code is not working as you define inline style css for hiding. which will never work for this scenario

Comment: False, jQuery will override this inline css with its own inline css. The show() function works something like this: 

if(element.style.display="none") {
   element.style.display="block";
}

The hide() function works the same way but it will hide the element.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged jQuery I made a jQuery answer. This is how I would do it:

**HTML**

```
<div id="tabs-1" class="tabContent" style="display: none">Tab1 info 1 content</div>
<div id="tabs-2" class="tabContent" style="display: none">Tab1 info 2 content</div>
<div id="tabs-3" class="tabContent" style="display: none">Tab1 info 3 content</div>
<ul class="side bar tabs">
  <li class="tabClicker" data-tab="tabs-1">Tab1 info 1</li>
  <li class="tabClicker" data-tab="tabs-2" >Tab1 info 2</li>
  <li class="tabClicker" data-tab="tabs-3">Tab1 info 3</li>  
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
    $(".tabClicker").click(function() {
        var tab = $(this).attr("data-tab");
        $(".tabContent").hide();
        $("#" + tab).show();
    });    
});
```

**DEMO** : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d2w9rvvt/)

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it doesn't display the content at all.  So you know, I'm placing this in Wordpress's Visual Content plugin.  My original code did display the content, but above code doesn't!

Comment: @user3610349 Are you sure you're using jQuery? As you see my demo is working. Note that I added some classes to the elements.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  I noticed the classes and how it works in demo, but for whatever reason it not working for me when I place them into my page.